# Asp.net authorization, maintenance mode

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authorization

In web.config, how could I perform the following?

If a user visits any page (except for /admin/), and is not logged in, redirect them to /maintenance.aspx. 
If the user visits /admin/ then allow them to view that page and login. Should also let the logged in user view the entire site.

Trying to restrict the site to only logged in users being able to view the site, but to also be able to view the login directory to login. If they're not logged in they always see that maintenance page, unless they visit the login URL.

Comment: Why the maintenance page, why not just redirect them to the `login URL`?

Comment: Because we don't want regular users shopping while we're getting the site ready for launch. Only admin users that know the login URL should be able to access the site.